How do I do with this logic using rust, what is the lifetime compiler inferred here?
pub struct SomeStruct {
    p1: Option<u32>,
    p2: SomeStruct2, // not pub 
    p3: Option<u32>,
    p4: SomeStruct2, // not pub
}

struct SomeStruct2;

impl SomeStruct {
    pub fn t1(&self) -> Result<(), &SomeStruct2> {
        if let Some(_) = self.p1 {
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(&self.p2)
        }
    }

    pub fn t2(&mut self) -> Result<(), &SomeStruct2> {
        self.t1()?;
        if self.p3.is_some() {
            self.p4 = SomeStruct2; // error here: 1. cannot assign to `self.p4` because it is borrowed
                                   // `self.p4` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(&self.p4)
        }
    }
}

fn make_test() {
    let mut a = SomeStruct {
        p1: Some(1),
        p2: SomeStruct2,
        p3: Some(2),
        p4: SomeStruct2,
    };
    a.t2();
}

As for the solution, all i can think of is call t1, do something with it and manually drop(<return value of t1()>) and then call t2.
pub struct SomeStruct {
    p1: Option<u32>,
    p2: SomeStruct2, // not pub
    p3: Option<u32>,
    p4: SomeStruct2, // not pub
}

struct SomeStruct2;

impl SomeStruct {
    pub fn t1(&self) -> Result<(), &SomeStruct2> {
        if let Some(_) = self.p1 {
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(&self.p2)
        }
    }

    pub fn t2(&mut self) -> Result<(), &SomeStruct2> {
        // self.t1()?;
        if self.p3.is_some() {
            self.p4 = SomeStruct2;
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(&self.p4)
        }
    }
}

fn make_test() {
    let mut a = SomeStruct {
        p1: Some(1),
        p2: SomeStruct2,
        p3: Some(2),
        p4: SomeStruct2,
    };
    let b = a.t1();
    if let Err(r) = b {
        // do something with r ( -> &SomeStruct2 )
    }
    drop(b);
    a.t2();
}


What is the exact lifetime inferred here?
And, is there any better rust way to deal with this kind of logic?

Shorter example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6bd08979bffbe2dd14594e4092d83710

@Cerberus thanks for pointing this out, but i still don't fully understand of the lifetime compiler inferred in this example yet.

self.t1()? borrows self and possibly returns something borrowed from self, it thus holds the borrow until the end of the function. The current borrow checker cannot tell that the borrow only happens together with an early return and hence keeps self borrowed until the end of the function for all branches even the one without an early return.
